# Angular 6 - Headers not being added on HTTP Post

Tags: angular

```
fileChange(event) {
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
if(fileList.length > 0) {
  let file: File = fileList[0];
  let formData:FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('files', file, file.name);

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
  headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/upload', formData, { headers: headers, method: 'POST' })
    .subscribe( res=> {
      console.log(res)
      //error => console.log(error)
    })
}
}
```

Result:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}
```

If I remove the need for Authorization it uploads fine, which leads me to believe it's something to do with the header.

Something is not right and I can't figure out what. I tried a bunch of alternatives and still stuck.

Comment: `headers = headers.append`. This returns new headers everytime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Authorization header is not allowing to upload the file on server. So you must add Authorization in your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to prevent the issue. Read more about the [issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/222)

Comment: But I'm not using CORS, I'm using a private REST client. I have no idea how to proceed in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is headers.set.
Please use this,

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
```

> Note: The difference between Headers.set and append() is that if the specified header already exists and accepts multiple values, Headers.set will overwrite the existing value with the new one, whereas append() will append the new value onto the end of the set of values.

Source: [append vs set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/append)

Comment: It has become clear to me that the problem is how I insert the headers in http.post(), I'm doing like so `{ headers: headers, method: 'POST' }`, and I'm getting error 500. On Postman it uploads fine with headers, and if I disable the need for authorization it also uploads fine.